# Stored Procedures in Derby

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

I am new to Derby and to databases in general for that matter. How can I create a prepared statment for an embedded derby database? Im not sure because the database is embedded.

My String is:

```
final String updateString = "create table " + TABLE_NAME_TBL_IPS + " (" +
                TABLE_COLUMN_COMPANY + " " + TABLE_COLUMN_COMPANY_DATA_TYPE+ "," +
                TABLE_COLUMN_IP + " " + TABLE_COLUMN_IP_DATA_TYPE + ")";
```

Also what is the benefit of using this as a stored procedure instead of a prepared statement call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if the database is embedded or not, as long as it has JDBC connectivity. In your case, Derby does provide you to the [connection information](http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/develop/develop26.html).

Your code may look something like this:-

```
// much easier to read with String.format()... in my opinion
final String updateString = String.format("create table %s (%s %s, %s %s)",
        TABLE_NAME_TBL_IPS,
        TABLE_COLUMN_COMPANY,
        TABLE_COLUMN_COMPANY_DATA_TYPE,
        TABLE_COLUMN_IP,
        TABLE_COLUMN_IP_DATA_TYPE);

Connection con = null;

try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:yourDatabaseName");

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    try {
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

Regarding your question whether to do so using a stored procedure or a `PreparedStatement`, there are bunch of information out there you are easily search. You generally use a stored procedure to group bunch of SQL statements whereas a `PreparedStatement` only allows you to execute one SQL statement. It is a good idea to use stored procedures if you intend to expose that API to allow your users to execute it regardless of technology (Java, .NET, PHP). However, if you are writing this SQL statement only for your Java application to work, then it makes sense to just use `PreparedStatement`.